# Implementing Foreign Keys in Legacy Data

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I recently re-built an internal website for our company, where we had to import data from the old application, which had no foreign key relationships, let alone constraints. All relationships were handled on the code side before.

Now that it's been rebuilt using .NET Core 2.0 and Entity Framework with strong typing and relationships, there is a lot of the legacy data tripping up my EF Migrations.

For example, we have a `Companies` table, with a "Responsible Employee" based on that Employee's `LdapID`. However, the old legacy data also had over 2,000 entries where someone had just input the Employee's name instead of their ID. I don't have permission to clean up this data, so that's not an option.

The site is already built to SHOW these "bad" values in the old data, but all of my migrations fail because of the FK Constraint; for example the `Employee ID` `Smith, Bob` doesn't match any IDs in the `Employee` table. Is there a way I can enforce Foreign Key relationships on new data, while allowing the old legacy data to continue with "bad" values? Right now, when I try to run a migration after adding a new column, this is what I get back:

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_Companies_Employees_EmployeeID". The conflict occurred in database
>   "ets_web", table "dbo.Employees", column 'LdapID'.

A temporary one-time fix won't work for me. I need to be able to create migrations that can be run by automated processes in our Test and Production environments. I could remove all constraints, but I'd rather leave that as a last resort.

Making the properties nullable won't fix this, because they are already nullable types, and nulls aren't the problem. It's when a Foreign Key `Company.EmployeeID` doesn't exist in the foreign table `Employee`. Similar issues exist in other tables, as well.

**Company.cs**

```
public class Company
{
    #region Main Properties
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(100)]
    [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "Address Line 1")]
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "Address Line 2")]
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "Address Line 3")]
    public string AddressLine3 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "City")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "State / Province")]
    public string StateID { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue("US")]
    [Display(Name = "Country")]
    public string CountryID { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(7, ErrorMessage = "Zip / Postal Code must be 7 characters or less."), DataType(DataType.PostalCode)]
    [Display(Name = "Zip / Postal Code")]
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }

    [StringLength(5)]
    [Display(Name = "Zip Code Suffix")]
    public string ZipSuffix { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    [Display(Name = "Contact Name")]
    public string ContactName { get; set; }

    [EmailAddress, StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "Contact Email")]
    public string ContactEmail { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Contact Phone"), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:(###) ###-####}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
    public long? ContactPhone { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Contact Fax"), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:(###) ###-####}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
    public long? ContactFax { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Responsible Employee")]
    public string EmployeeID { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// This property is used for concurrency, to prevent two users from submitting conflicting updates.
    /// </summary>
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Navigation Properties
    public virtual State State { get; set; }

    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }

    // THIS is where the FK Relationship issue lies.
    [ForeignKey("EmployeeID")]
    public virtual Employee ResponsibleEmployee { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

**Employee.cs**

```
[Table("Employees")]
public class Employee
{
    #region Main Properties
    // This value is generated by our LDAP user system and input manually during Employee creation in the new system.
    [Key, Required, StringLength(20), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Display(Name = "LDAP / Global ID")]
    public string LdapID { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(35)]
    public string Department { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50), DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Work Phone"), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:(###) ###-####}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
    public long? WorkPhone { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Mobile Phone"), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:(###) ###-####}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
    public long? MobilePhone { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    [Display(Name = "Fax Number")]
    public string Fax { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    [Display(Name = "Mail Stop")]
    public string MailStop { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [Display(Name = "Last Login"), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d MMM yyyy h:mm tt} UTC", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? LastLogin { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used to modify security permissions for the user.
    /// <para>Possible values are: 0 - Disabled, 1 - Read Only, 2 - Read/Write, 3 - Loan Admin, 4 - Super Admin</para>
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = "Access Level")]
    public AccessType AccessLevel { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// This property is used for concurrency, to prevent two users from submitting conflicting updates.
    /// </summary>
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Navigation Properties
    [Display(Name = "Responsible Companies")]
    public virtual ICollection<Company> ResponsibleCompanies { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Employee")]
    [Display(Name = "History")]
    public virtual ICollection<History> History { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Unmapped Properties
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the user's full name in the format: Lastname, Firstname
    /// </summary>
    [NotMapped]
    [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
    public string FullName => $"{LastName}, {FirstName}";
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: You could create `int Id` property to be the key on the `Employee` table  instead of trying to accomodate for legacy data if you can't clean up the data.

Comment: This is a good idea, but I'd like to keep `LdapID` as the PK if possible. There are a lot of related views to the Employee object, and I'd like to avoid loading the Employee data in each of these views just to display their ID in the box. But your idea is definitely a better backup than my original idea of wiping out all constraints.

Comment: You could constraint the table conditionally based on a regular expression maybe. I have done something like that with a regular constraint not FK so not sure exactly if it would work for FK's. So my idea is like if your `LdapID` is supposed to consist of numbers only, but sometimes consists  of letters, then that sort of conditional constraint might work. Having said that, the EF might freak out if you're messing about like that, but could be worth a try.

Comment: I ended up turning the Legacy column into a non-FK field, and added a new FK. I've added a "Patch" in the code that checks if it's been run, and if not, copies known `LdapID`s into the FK field, and reuses the old column as a "Lastname, Firstname" field so I don't need to load `Employee.Name` constantly. It's a bit of a performance hog on first run after migration, but it gets the job done in a way that keeps our Continuous Integration intact. Appreciate the suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this problem before.  To the best of my knowledge you have 2 options

- Script out values for all the ones that do not have a relation with dummy data and continue with what you're doing.
- Use [ModelState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstate(v=vs.118).aspx) as server side validation to enforce this requirement upon post.

Comment: I ended up blending your idea a bit with Vidmantas' idea. I removed the Foreign Key from the legacy column, added a new FK column, and create a first-time-run patch in the code that will copy known LdapIDs into the new FK, or leaves it null for Legacy data. I then modified ModelState to force LdapID to be valid for any Create/Update requests, so it forces the users to update Legacy data that wasn't patched due to missing Employee references.